# Store each byte from 8-byte value in array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a large array of bytes called memory and a `uint64_t` value called `valA`. I want each byte in `valA` to be stored in a position in memory (each position in memory holds one byte). The position in memory I'm starting from is 3832.

This is what I've coded so far:

```
uint64_t valA = 81985529216486895;
memory[3832] = valA;
```

When I print out each position in memory:

```
printf("number in memory - %d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
       memory[valE+0], memory[valE+1], memory[valE+2], memory[valE+3],
       memory[valE+4], memory[valE+5], memory[valE+6], memory[valE+7]);
```

The output is "number in memory- 2390000000". I want the output to be the original number that was stored in `valA`. Any suggestions?

Comment: By "memory" do you mean "RAM" or do you mean some arbitrary array called memory?

Comment: arbitrary array called memory

Comment: Outputting a byte at a time will not allow you to regenerate the decimal number in `valA`.  If you presented the number in `valA` as hexadecimal, then you could print the bytes as hexadecimal and could recreate the original number.  You've not shown how the data in `valA` is available anywhere in `memory`; you've not shown how `memory` is defined.  At the moment, your question is unanswerable.  (Note how a systematic layout makes it easier to read the `printf()` statement.)  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll make sure any other future questions are improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the output to be the original number that was stored in `valA`

It is not going to work with decimal output, because decimal representation does not break at byte's boundary. You can get it to work with hexadecimal notation, though:

```
long long unsigned int valA = 81985529216486895LL;
uint8_t memory[5000];
uint32_t valE = 3832;
memcpy(&memory[valE], &valA, sizeof(valA));
printf(
    "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x\n"
,   memory[valE+7]
,   memory[valE+6]
,   memory[valE+5]
,   memory[valE+4]
,   memory[valE+3]
,   memory[valE+2]
,   memory[valE+1]
,   memory[valE+0]
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/eMCL15)

Note that the bytes are ordered in reverse to match the ordering on the demo system.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the memcpy() function.